# Displaying a image which is fetched from a http link and displayed in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I was making a simple weather app to practive tkinter. during the process I encountered a major issue, the image i got could be fetched using request and displaying it in a new tkinter window was a great problem. The program is still incomplete but it works fine except the image could not be displayed.

Inside the disp_weather() you can see i have created a new window to display details, the fw.get_icon() gets the url for the png image for eg like "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png" and the error arises

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abhishek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop\OIBSIP\proj3_weather\Init.py", line 23, in disp_weather
    imag.pack()
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

The program:

```
import fetch_weather as fw
from tkinter import *
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests
from io import BytesIO

def disp_weather():
    location=e1.get()
    unit=v.get()
    url=fw.get_icon()
    url="https:"+url
    new_window = Toplevel(root)
    new_window.geometry("300x200")
    new_window.title("New Window")
    
    response = requests.get(url) 
    img_data = BytesIO(response.content)
    img = Image.open(img_data)
    wImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    imag = Label(new_window, image=wImg)  #Here is where the problem starts
    imag.photo = wImg
    imag.pack()
    

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
icon_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "weather.ico")
icon_path=icon_path.replace("\\", "/")

root = Tk()
root.title("Weather")
root.iconbitmap(default=icon_path)
root.geometry("400x300")

Label(root, text='Enter the Location:').grid(row=0, column=0, pady=4, sticky=W)

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, sticky=W)

v = IntVar()
Label(root,text='Choose a unit:').grid(row=1,column=0,pady=5,sticky=W)
Radiobutton(root, text='Celsius', variable=v, value=1).grid(row=1, column=1, pady=4, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(root, text='Fahrenheit', variable=v, value=2).grid(row=1, column=2, pady=4, sticky=W)

fetch_button = Button(root, text="Find", command=disp_weather)
fetch_button.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, columnspan=3)

mainloop()
```

Comment: The error traceback is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to debug your program (e.g. what is actually the `response` returned from the server?). Substituting the URL for `"https://cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png"` I get correct result:

```py
import os
from io import BytesIO
from tkinter import *

import requests
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def disp_weather():
    location = e1.get()
    unit = v.get()
    url = "https://cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png"
    new_window = Toplevel(root)
    new_window.geometry("300x200")
    new_window.title("New Window")

    response = requests.get(url)
    img_data = BytesIO(response.content)
    img = Image.open(img_data)
    wImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    imag = Label(new_window, image=wImg)
    imag.photo = wImg
    imag.pack()


root = Tk()
root.title("Weather")
root.geometry("400x300")

Label(root, text="Enter the Location:").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=4, sticky=W)

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, sticky=W)

v = IntVar()
Label(root, text="Choose a unit:").grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(root, text="Celsius", variable=v, value=1).grid(
    row=1, column=1, pady=4, sticky=W
)
Radiobutton(root, text="Fahrenheit", variable=v, value=2).grid(
    row=1, column=2, pady=4, sticky=W
)

fetch_button = Button(root, text="Find", command=disp_weather)
fetch_button.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, columnspan=3)

mainloop()
```

Downloads and displays the image correctly:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, if I use just the url its working fine but when i try to fetch it dynamicallly its not displaying